# Bootx64.efi not working from EFI

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, windows-11

I have followed [this](https://swapn652.hashnode.dev/dual-booting-linux-made-easy-no-usb-drive-required) tutorial to dual boot my Windows 11 because I have done dual booting before from USB (which doesn't mean I am good at this), I just wanna learn how to do this without an external drive of any kind. Everything went right until selecting boot the EFI from the boot menu, I can see the bootx64.efi under the UUI partition there but after selecting it goes to Windows instead of the Ubuntu installer. I am using an HP Victus Laptop and have disabled secure boot and can't find any legacy options in the bios.

Here's some [pics](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e93VbIIIJ6HP8E7YJtmzi20tjjYNhyLr?usp=sharing) of it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I dunno what you mean by clarify my problem, like inorder to dual boot, i usually setup a usb device and select efi from boot menu then navigate to bootx64.efi, but with the partition method i done after selecting efi, it goes to windows instead of ubuntu installer

Comment: Over your head ? (Is it some technical term or an english slang ?). Well, I have tried VM, but I need to use my RTX as i am developing some things that need it. No offence, but i had like to get an answer or lead about what could be going wrong, rather than alternate methods. Cause even tho I can do the same with a USB Stick, my goal is to learn without it

Comment: Can't do that either, cause this is my recently bought laptop for college (around 6 months ago). And I do all my work in this and don't have any other systems with me as i sold my previous one. Again as said, i am more into finding solution to the current problem not about alternatives

Comment: Please ignore the comments from the VM evangelist. Such discussion would be OK in a forum, not here. The first thing you should do - assuming the installation was done correctly - is to open UEFI ("BIOS") > Boot menu and select "Ubuntu" in the "OS selection" setting or equivalent. Worse case scenario your HP is one of those that boot Windows no matter what, in which case you're restricted to boot using the F9 key right after powering it on. It's a simple as that, again, assuming the installation was correct. AND re-enable Secure Boot because it's a requirement for Windows 11.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Well, my winodws works without the secure boot, it did ask for a secure key or something. And sorry for the confusion but i Haven't installed ubuntu yet, I am having problem in the step where i have to chose the installable USB (but i am using a partition of my disk : FAT32 and with just the iso Flashed)

Comment: And is there a way to know if my lap is only for windows ?

Comment: 1. Use an USB dongle like everybody else. 2. BEFORE starting the installation make sure to disable Windows Fast Startup "feature" and shutdown properly. 3. That ot works without SB doesn't mean it should (and SB is useful for everybody, period).

Comment: *And is there a way to know if my lap is only for windows?* There's no such thing. There are hardware with better or worse support and the situation I commented above has nothing to do with it, the problem is ONLY when multi-booting (Ubuntu standalone boiots fine) and the ONLY inconvenient is having to explicitly select Ubuntu at the start.

Comment: I understand that using a USB stick is the much better way, But my qn is if this way is possible, it seems like working for others but i just wanna know why not mine and well a quick google search said my laptop should support dual boot. I have to do this dual boot before monday as I will be starting the coming project with seniors. I could borrow a USB stick as a last resort, for now I just wanna figure this out

Comment: And well, standalone ubuntu is not under my coonsideration cause well......... games and stuff, i will try disabling fast startup and will update rn.

Comment: There are ways to boot the ISO directly but it needs Grub already installed, I think. Either way, it may create problems and unnecessary pitfalls. I can help you with the typical installation.

Comment: Well can you help me with the current situation tho ?  I just wanna know how this goes. Like as of my knowledge this thing should work, like it is recognizing the partition and the bootx64, but is not going into it

Comment: No, I won't help you with that, I may help you with the standard installation, and not your "bro", to be clear.

Comment: Well then, thanks for your time.